# awk not printing out to file when i use >>

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am having this below script , the output is printed in the terminal but not to the file   ,what i may be missing

```
awk '{if($0~/\/regression\//){sub(/\/regression\//,"|",$0)}} {print $0}' testreport | sed 's#/\([^/]*\.utt\)#|\1#'||sed 's#\(.*\)/#\1|#'| awk '{gsub(/\//,".");print}'| awk -F'[|]' '{print $2,"|",$3,"|",$4,"|",$6,"|",$7,"|",$8,"|",$9,"|",$10}'| awk '{sub(/\..*/,"",$1)}10' >> report3
```

Comment: Pretty sure you should only have 1 `>`, and it doesn't look like you specified an extension (such as `.txt`)

Comment: @Vince That's not the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two vertical bars after your second command in the pipe chain (an `sed` command) which made shell interpret it as an OR operator.

Drop one of the vertical bars to make shell correctly treat it as a pipe.

```
sed 's#/\([^/]*\.utt\)#|\1#'||sed
                            ^^
```

Comment: ... and then throw away the whole thing and write one small, trivial awk script to do everything instead!